# how to use shared preference with image view and sent to next activity

Tags: android

How can i choose photo and take picture from camera and sent to next Activity with shared preference

this is from function camara

```
btncamera.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat")
        public void onClick(View v) {
            SharedPreferences app_preferences =
                    PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(Showpic_resumeActivity.this);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = app_preferences.edit();

                    String imageview_re = imageView1.getContext().toString();
                    editor.putString("key6", imageview_re);

            Intent intentcamera = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
            String imageFileName = "IMG_" + timeStamp + ".jpg";
            File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "DCIM/Camera/" + imageFileName);
            uri = Uri.fromFile(f);



            intentcamera.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uri);

            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intentcamera, "Take a picture with"), REQUEST_CAMERA);
            editor.commit();

            Intent myIntent = new Intent(Showpic_resumeActivity.this,Showdata_result_resume.class);
            startActivity(myIntent);

        }
    });
```

this is Aticity  i want to result

```
SharedPreferences app_preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
     String imgview_resume = app_preferences.getString("key6", "null");
        imageresume.set(imgview_resume);
```

i have Error this line   imageresume.set(imgview_resume);  i should use .set ?

Comment: Oh. You should first read some basic java.

Comment: Have you read this? http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html
All the answers are there

Comment: sorry i dont understand

Answer (score 0):

convert ImageView Drawable to bitmap-to byte Array-to Base 64 and store in Shared preference

```
BitmapDrawable drawable = (BitmapDrawable) iv.getDrawable();
Bitmap bmap= drawable.getBitmap();
ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();  
bmap.compress(CompressFormat.PNG,100,bos); 
byte[] bb = bos.toByteArray();
String image =Base64.encodeToString(bb, Base64.DEFAULT).trim();
```

Comment: remove this   String imageview_re = imageView1.getContext().toString();and put suggested code .

Comment: And put String image in SharedPref

Comment: i has some error  iv.getDrawable  nad  Base64.encodeBytes(bb)